Can I deploy SPL and ATA programs to the same address on a fork of Solana
I’m working on an SVM based network, and having the token and ata programs at different ids causes a lot of manual changes needed. Is it possible to deploy these to the same address as mainnet without the private key? Even though I’m not running a fork of their ledger, it’s a full fork from genesis.

Certainly! Genesis allows you to specify any extra accounts, and the SPL programs are fetched by the fetch-spl.sh script at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/master/fetch-spl.sh
If you want, you can run the script locally, and then replace the output programs with your modified versions before running solana-genesis and starting your bootstrap node.
